# How do I combine overflow visible and scroll?

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I have a slider component that I'm building. It uses the Bootstrap .container class to be contained in a specified page width, but needs to overflow to the right side of the screen. If I use overflow-x: visible it overflows to the right, but then the whole page scrolls. If I give the parent overflow: hidden then I am not able to scroll through the slider.

What would be the best way to allow both overflow-x: visible and allow scrolling with a scrollbar at the same time without the entire page being affected?

HTML

```
<div id="main-container">
    <section class="container">
        <ul class="panels">
            <li class="panel"></li>
            <li class="panel"></li>
            <li class="panel"></li>
            <li class="panel"></li>
            <li class="panel"></li>
            <li class="panel"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.panels {
   overflow-x: visible;
   display: flex;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use `overflow-x: scroll;`?

Comment: A scrollbar appears when content is higher/wider than the parent, the parent has a specific width/height and is set not to expand with the content. If parent happens to be the `body` of the page, or a container containing all the content, then everything will scroll. So either you have to place the scrolling part in its own container, or make everything not supposed to scroll fixed. But we can't help you with that, as you provided no code at all.

Comment: @AasthaBist If I use overflow-x: scroll it adds the scrollbar but clips the slides to the container. I want the slides to overflow the container but not overflow the page content.

Comment: I've added some code to give an idea of what I have so far, and everything is great except for not being able to scroll through the panels.

Answer (score 0):

I created this because it's a problem I keep re-writing myself so this is both for you and me as a reminder of how it works :)

A horizontally scrollable "carousel" style bootstrap row with no scrollbars

```css
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid overflow-scroll">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-visible">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-primary">asdfafd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="bg-light">asd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfa
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfaf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```